# Hidden navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

My navigation is not showing when window is resized and navi open by button. I tried use z-index, but this does't work. What is the problem?

[image: nav is hidden by button]
[image: Nav open by button, but hidden]
[image: Nav in normal window size]

JS file, when the window resized, then nav displayed block and hidden and open by button.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("HeaderNav");
  if (x.className === "Header__Content") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "Header__Content";
  }
}
```

```css
/* HEADER */

.Header {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.Header__Content__Left {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  height: 70px;
  width: 30%;
}

.Header__Content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 10;
}

.Header__Content a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.Header__Content a:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 25px;
}

.Header__Content a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.Header__Content .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .Header__Content a {
    overflow: visible;
    display: none;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .Header__Content a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .Header__Content.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .Header__Content.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .Header__Content.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/* SLIDER */

.Slider {
  display: table;
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Header,
.Slider {
  z-index: 1;
  background: url("../img/apartment-3564955_1920.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.Header__Content__Left,
.Header__Content,
.Slider__Bottom,
.Slider__Content,
.Slider__Right {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: .6;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Slider__Section {
  height: 85%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Slider__Content {
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 55%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Slider__Clear {
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Slider__Right {
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Slider__Bottom {
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header class="Header">
  <div class="Header__Content__Left"></div>
  <div class="Header__Content" id="HeaderNav">
    <a href="History">История</a>
    <a href="Portfolio">Портфолио</a>
    <a href="Services">Услуги</a>
    <a href="Contacts">Контакты</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
<main class="Content">
  <div class="Slider">
    <div class="Slider__Section">
      <div class="Slider__Content"></div>
      <div class="Slider__Clear"></div>
      <div class="Slider__Right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Slider__Bottom"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The shared code doesn't seem to reproduce the given images, try running the snippet in question. I don't see the hambuger menu in small resolution

Comment: Also where is the code that calls `myFunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've set a height to your navigation class.

```
.Header__Content {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

that's why u cant see your navigation if it's open.
Add for example this:

```
.Header__Content.responsive {
     position: relative;
     height: auto;
}
```

And you will see your navigation.